# Getting Error while running PIG script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
x = load '/home/manish/Work/inputs/testInput.txt' using PigStorage(',') AS (key:chararray , value:int);
y = group x bt key;
r = foreach y { m = generate x.value AS one; ord_m = ORDER m BY one desc; lim_m = LIMIT ord_m 3; generate group, lim_m;};
```

getting **ERROR** as:

```
2014-12-09 20:07:45,978 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 4, column 29>  mismatched input 'x' expecting LEFT_PAREN
```

i.e at the third line.

```
r = foreach y { m = generate x.value AS one; ord_m = ORDER m BY one desc; lim_m = LIMIT ord_m 3; generate group, lim_m;};
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you are trying in this script?. you cannot use generate command without foreach.

Comment: My input is of the format:1,3
1,4
3,78
2,5
3,6
6,76
2,45
3,65
3,45
4,45  Now I want my o/p of the format:
1 3,4
2 4,45
3 45,65,78 like this.

Comment: that is why I wanted to sort it on x.value rather than x.
If possible try it. I am facing an issue on this. Anyways thanks for replying

Comment: Thanks accomplished it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
x = load '/home/manish/Work/inputs/testInput.txt' using PigStorage(',') AS (key:int , value:int);
y = group x by key;
r = foreach y {
                 ord_m = ORDER x BY value  desc;
                 lim_m = LIMIT ord_m 3;
                 generate group, lim_m;
              };
dump r;
```